# How to draw onto a PictureBox image when control resizes?

Tags: winforms, picturebox

I am using the pictureBox_Paint event to try and draw an overlay onto the image in a PictureBox. 
This is working fine until I resize the PictureBox (set to use SizeMode.Zoom), when I do this the overlay graphic is drawn off position by the margin between the image and the edge of the PictureBox. I guess I need to use the ImageRectangle somehow but this is not public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a custom usercontrol instead, you would have much more control, and would not be difficult to build.